# Matplotlib Line Rotation or Animation

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have created a polar plot and would like to mimic a doppler. This includes a 360 degree sweep around the circle (polar plot). Once the sweep gets to 360 degrees, it needs to go back to zero and continue the sweep.

How do I animate or rotate this line to constantly sweep around this circle? I only want one line to constantly sweep around this plot.

I have looked at several different examples, however, none that create this rotation.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
import time

r = 90  * (math.pi/180)
t = 50000
az = 90
el = 5

fig = pylab.figure(figsize = [5.0, 5.0])
ax = fig.gca(projection = 'polar')
fig.canvas.set_window_title('Doppler')
ax.plot(r, t, color ='b', marker = 'o', markersize = '3')
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

currTime = time.time()
prevTime = currTime - 1
deltaTime = currTime - prevTime

outer_border_width = 1

screen_width = 500
screen_height = 500

midpoint = [int(screen_width/2), int(screen_height/2)]
radius = (midpoint[0])
sweep_length = radius - outer_border_width

angle = 50
sweep_interval = 10
sweep_speed = sweep_interval

x = sweep_length * math.sin(angle) + int(screen_width/2)
y = sweep_length * math.cos(angle) + int(screen_height/2)

az = az + ((360.0 / sweep_interval ) * deltaTime)

line1 = (midpoint, [50000, 50000])
#line2 = (midpoint, [20000, 20000])

ax.plot(line1, color = 'b', linewidth = 1)

#Increase the angle by 0.05 radians
angle = angle - sweep_speed

#Reset the angle to 0
if angle > 2 * math.pi:
    angle = angle - 2 * math.pi

#ax.plot(line2, color = 'r', linewidth = 1)
#ax.lines.pop(0)

plt.show()
```

Below is a picture of what it currently looks like for reference: 
[image]

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not understand much of your code, but in order to produce an animation you can use `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation`. Here, you'd give an array of angles to an updating function, which sets the data of the line for each frame.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation

r = 90  * (np.pi/180)
t = 50000

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection = 'polar')
fig.canvas.set_window_title('Doppler')
ax.plot(r, t, color ='b', marker = 'o', markersize = '3')
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_ylim(0,1.02*t)

line1, = ax.plot([0, 0],[0,t], color = 'b', linewidth = 1)

def update(angle):
    line1.set_data([angle, angle],[0,t])
    return line1,

frames = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,120)

fig.canvas.draw()
ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=frames, blit=True, interval=10)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I really like your animation and want to ask how can i modify the rotational speed of the vector and if a stopwatch since i want to stop the animation after 1 second

Comment: @Jung You can adapt the number of frames (i.e. the 120 in the code), or the `interval`.

Comment: thanks! how can i set the start position 90 degreea?